# always write the default selection and never change although if I select different selection on spinner

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner

I have 2 spinner. This part of code read the selection from spinner and write to text file. The problem always write the default selection and never change although if I select different selection on spinner.Please help.

```
    package com.apps.androidapps10;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button hantarBtn;
    private static final String TAG = "MEDIA";
    String namaJalan = "";
    String namaLorong = "";
    String noKenderaan;
    private String filename = "SampleFile.txt";
    private String filepath = "MyFileStroage";
    File myExternalFile;
    EditText inputText;
    String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        hantarBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        try {

            BufferedReader bReader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                    (getAssets().open("jalan.txt")));
            ArrayList<String> jalan = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line = bReader.readLine();
            while (line != null){
                jalan.add(line);
                line = bReader.readLine();

            }

            bReader.close();

            Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,jalan);
            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

            namaJalan = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();




        }catch (IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader bReader1 =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                    (getAssets().open("lorong.txt")));
            ArrayList<String> lorong = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line = bReader1.readLine();
            while (line != null){
                lorong.add(line);
                line = bReader1.readLine();

            }

            bReader1.close();

            Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lorong);
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

            namaLorong = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }






        hantarBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile,true);
                    fos.write(inputText.getText().toString().getBytes());
                    fos.write("\t".getBytes());
                    fos.write(namaJalan.toString().getBytes());
                    fos.write("\t".getBytes());
                    fos.write(namaLorong.toString().getBytes());
                    fos.write("\r\n".getBytes());
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write Done...",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Failed to write");
                }

            }
        });

        if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
            hantarBtn.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your spinner variables to the top (The same place you have `Button hantarBtn;`), then move your code to get the values from the spinners into the `onClickListener`:

```
public class MainActivity{
    Spinner spinner1;  // There's another way of doing this,
    Spinner spinner2;  // but putting them here should be easiest
    // The rest of your member variables

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        // the rest of your code

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                // Make sure to get the values when the button is clicked
                selectedItem1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                selectedItem2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                // whatever else you want to do when the button is clicked
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am still facing so many problem in this spinner. do you have any sample that i can refer. Thank you so much

Comment: @NeshMogan I've updated my answer. You were getting the values from the spinners only when the activity was created. You have to get the values when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use resource for handling file operation (reading / writing).
2. Separate the write to file to another function, then call it later
3. The spinner use AdapterView will use the setOnItemSelectedListener() function, not setOnClickListener() of View

**Use it as below**

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, 
   int position, long id) {
    // write to file
}

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
   }
});
```